# Is ZFC arithmetically sound?

Tags: set-theory, foundations, natural-numbers, philosophy

I apologize that this question is fairly philosophical and not purely mathematical. For the purposes of this question, I would like to take the point of view that that natural numbers are "real" and so every statement made about them is either true or false, while the universe of sets is a convenient "fiction". Basically it's Platonism for numbers and formalism for sets. From this point of view, is there a convincing argument that every theorem proven by ZFC about the natural numbers is actually true?

I'm guessing that it is only possible to make this convincing argument for certain statements about the natural numbers. For example if ZFC proves $\forall x\in \mathbb{N}\ \phi(x)$ for some quantifier-free $\phi$, then the consistency of ZFC should be enough to justify the truth of $\forall x \ \phi(x).$ If there were some counterexample $y$ where $\phi(y)$ fails then ZFC would prove $\exists x\in \mathbb{N} \ \neg \phi(x),$ an inconsistency. This argument should work with sentences that have any number of universal quantifiers, that is $\Pi_1$ formulas.

Edit: I have read that ZFC and ZF prove the same arithmetical sentences, so this should be equivalent to asking whether ZF is arithmetically sound.

Comment: This follows from certain common hypotheses like the existence of a strongly inaccessible cardinal. The existence of such a cardinal means that all provable statements in ZFC are true about the entire arithmetic hierarchy. The consistency of ZFC is equivalent to saying that all $\Pi^0_1$ statements provable in ZFC are true.

Comment: @MarkSaving That's very interesting. The main point I am confused on is, if one is dubious about ZFC, it seems like one would be even more dubious about ZFC $+$ exists inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: Sorry - strongly inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @subrosar Unqualified "inaccessible" generally means "strongly inaccessible', so you're fine (and, incidentally, the arithmetical soundness of ZFC also follows from the existence of a weakly inaccessible cardinal).

Comment: A similar question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/5hfck8/the_unreasonable_effectiveness_of_zfc/

Comment: @subrosar I definitely understand where you’re coming from with your philosophical objection. The problem is that the incompleteness theorem means that you need something stronger than ZFC to prove a statement like this. Ultimately, I suspect that you have to believe in ZF or something equally philosophically dubious in order to conclude that ZFC is correct. Note that ZF and ZFC prove the same first-order claims about natural numbers.